# Returning a List from REST API call

Tags: scala, rest, spray

I am fairly new to spray, and I would like to extract the result returned by [this](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items) API to a list variable.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't use spray but you need to use the HTTP client to make the request and use a JSON parser to parse that returned list. You might get better responses if you post code snippet(s) showing what you have done and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

If we ignore error handling, you could do it like so:

```
import scala.io.Source
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
...
val source = Source.fromURL("https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items")
val json = source.mkString.parseJson
val list = json.convertTo[List[Int]]
```